# In background.html,how can I access current web page to get dom

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In background.html,I want to get current web page dom.
such as "getElementById()

Comment: Yeah, how can i get current web page dom?

Answer (score 7):

To do this, you would need to use [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). Message passing is needed to allow you to communicate to the DOM, and the only way to communicate to the DOM is through Content-Scripts. I will show you two ways which you can do this:

## Method 1

Having every visited page listen for an extension request

### background.html

```
<html>
<script>
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getHTML"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

### content_script.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getHTML")
      sendResponse({data: document.getElementById('header').innerHTML});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

## Method 2

Only execute a content script whenever you need to:

### background.html

```
<html>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'execute.js'});
});

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('Data Recieved: ' + request.data);
});
</script>
</html>
```

### execute.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({data: document.getElementById('header').innerHTML});
```

Answer (score -4):

Hit CTRL+SHIFT+I for the developer UI oder CTRL+U for the source