# Obtain cookies of the page being visited

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

I want to know how can we obtain the cookies of the current page being accessed using a communication link between the content script and background page. This is for an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to access `document.cookie` for each website you visit. Then you can use [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to pass the cookies from your Content Script to your [Background Page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html).

There are many examples on Stack Overflow for example:

- [Chrome Extension: how to capture selected text and send to a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626859/chrome-extension-how-to-capture-selected-text-and-send-to-a-web-service)
- [Chrome Extension: How to pass a variable from Content Script to background.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674958/chrome-extension-how-to-pass-a-variable-from-content-script-to-background-html)
- [Google Chrome Extension - Architecture Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722268/google-chrome-extension-architecture-question)
- [Chrome extension: accessing localStorage in content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937000/chrome-extension-accessing-localstorage-in-content-script)
- [In background.html,how can I access current web page to get dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779579/in-background-html-how-can-i-access-current-web-page-to-get-dom)
- [Help with chrome extension message passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588438/help-with-chrome-extension-message-passing)

Comment: I have created a script and a background page but seem to work rite since nothing is there in the console when i run the extension