# chrome.permissions is not available in Edge extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am porting my Chrome extension to work in Microsoft Edge. I used Microsoft's toolkit and bridged the code. But i get an error is console saying "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'contains' of undefined or null reference". This is thrown at the place where i have called chrome.permissions.contains.

Let me know if there is a solution for this or if there is a documentation for all these incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is not currently supported by Edge. Microsoft lists it as "Under consideration".

So the only solutions are:

- Do not use `chrome.permissions` in your port. Probably by granting the widest permissions possible. Unpleasant, but you have to explain to users that it's a platform limitation.
- Wait until it is supported (which is not guaranteed; FF's WebExtension platform doesn't support them yet either).

The roadmap of API support is here: [Microsoft Edge extension API roadmap](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/extension-API-roadmap/)

Detailed list of supported APIs with known issues/incompatibilities: [Supported APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/supported-APIs/)

Comment: Thanks and any idea about chrome.cookies ? I see that it is present in supported API doc but it keeps throwing "undefined" error.

Comment: Did you declare the permission to use it?

Comment: I included "cookies" under permissions in manifest.json and included the domain name in the permissions as well.

Comment: Are you trying to [use it from a content script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6850787/934239)?

Comment: No this extension is of chrome's and it works in chrome browser but not with edge. It is not used in a content script

Comment: Have you looked at the second link? It's not fully supported (`onChanged` isn't)

Comment: chrome.cookies.getAll({ "url": cookie_domain }, function(cookies){console.error("name: "+cookies[0].value);}); this return "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference".

Comment: Well there are no cookies for this domain. The code doesn't consider that a possibility and craps itself. API not at fault. I think it's pointless to continue this discussion in comments - ask a new question if you think it's worth discussing.